# TFS 2012 automatically build projects that depend on current one

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, build-automation, tfsbuild

Ok so I have to admit, I'm very new to all of this build automation stuff. But basically what I'm wondering is if there is a way to wire up my build definitions in such a way that if I have a case like so

- ProjectA produces ComponentA.dll
- ProjectB references ComponentA.dll and produces ComponentB.dll
- ProjectC references ComponentB.dll

then when I make changes to ProjectA and check them in, the build process would automatically also build ProjectB, and finally ProjectC, and report any errors.

So is there a way to accomplish this, or should this type of thing be handled somehow completely differently in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process you are referring to is the crux of the practice known as [***Continuous Integration***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).

TFS does it very well: simply set your build definition [`Trigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190718#reason_individual_ci) to `Continuous Integration` and set the [`Workspace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190721.aspx) working folder to the parent folder of the three projects. This way, any change in one of the projects will trigger a build.

[MSDN: Build and Deploy Continuously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308011.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, the msdn link you provided seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a visual studio solution and use project references between the projects.   Then build the solution on your build server.